# Azure action group not sending emails for outlook contact group

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

I want to configure an alert in Azure portal. When it fires, I want to send a notification to a contact group, for example: mygroup@xxx.com.
I choose action type: Email/SMS/Push/Voice
Interesting thing: when I set up action group not for a contact group, but for my personal email - I see the alert in my mailbox.
Is there any way to configure action group for a contact group consisting of emails?
Is there a whitelist/blacklist configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Verify that emails from these three addresses are not blocked:
>
> azure-noreply@microsoft.com
>
> azureemail-noreply@microsoft.com
>
> alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com
>
> It is common that internal
>   mailing lists or distribution lists block emails from external email
>   addresses. You need to whitelist the above email addresses. To test,
>   add a regular work email address (not a mailing list) to the action
>   group and see if alerts arrive to that email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

Note also that sometimes MS/Azure IPs get blacklisted as well, and the Azure Portal will still say the notification was "fired" with no indication it failed.  Sad, but true.

Check this link for more detail: [Azure Action Group email notifications - fail, not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74944779/azure-action-group-email-notifications-fail-not-reliable)